# Removing the @-Tag from a message (command) Discord JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I tried to make a mute command with the @-Tag. I got alle the stuff for mute going but I want to implement a reason. If the Players name ist for example "Abc Abc A#0001" the bot would show in the reason message to the user "Abc A#0001".

I tried:

```
.replace(event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0).getAsMention() + " ", "");
```

= full name will be shown

and

```
.replace(args[1] + " ", "");
```

= "Abc A#0001" ist shown

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to get for example "Full Username#0001", you can use [getAsTag()](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/User.html#getAsTag()) from the User object instead of getAsMention()

Comment: Doesn't work. If I do it like that it just shows the whole message without the command

!ban @ ab abc#0001 hello
reason to the user: @ ab abc#0001 hello